# Parameter language in vimeo for the error message

Tags: vimeo

There are a param as youtube that have 'hl' but for Vimeo? I am looking for, but i can't found. I need this, for the message error when the video doesn't exist

I search in the vimeo API, but unfortunately no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my check, Vimeo API doesn't have any support for language filtering via API, but i will check if we can pass this as a product feedback for our roadmap.

Best,
Tamer